# TypeError: item.optional_fields.map is not a function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am trying to map a function but in mean time it give me error , could someone please help me how to resolve this issue . I really need to be done issue soon . Thanks

**Array**

```
 optional_fields: "[{"fieldName":"field 1","fieldType":{"value":"text","label":"Text"}},
  {"fieldName":"field 2","fieldType":{"value":"dropdown","label":"Dropdown"},"value":[{"label":"new value","value":"new value","__isNew__":true},
    {"label":"value 1","value":"value 1","__isNew__":true}]}]"
```

**Code**

```
 {JSON.parse(item.optional_fields.map((item) => (
     <td>{item.fieldName}</td>
  ))
```

)}

Comment: @AlleXyS Actually , I am fetching it from server . In creation form when I submit form I was sending data as `JSON.stringify` but did not parse to render items .

Comment: and Item is self map function like  editData.map((item)=>.... )}

Comment: try `JSON.parse(item.optional_fields).map(.....  ) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you've missed a bracket in your code, this should work:

```
 {
  JSON.parse(item.optional_fields).map(item => <td>{item.fieldName}</td>)
 }
```

```js
var optional_fields=JSON.stringify([{"fieldName":"field 1","fieldType":{"value":"text","label":"Text"}},
  {"fieldName":"field 2","fieldType":{"value":"dropdown","label":"Dropdown"},"value":[{"label":"new value","value":"new value","__isNew__":true},
    {"label":"value 1","value":"value 1","__isNew__":true}]}])
    
console.log(JSON.parse(optional_fields).map(item =>item))
```

Comment: getting this error TypeError: JSON.parse(...).map is not a function

Comment: Can you provide the whole object?